# How to show image in JOptionPane in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, joptionpane, imageicon

The code I used in `JGrasp` to show the image is not working in Netbeans

The code I used in `JGrasp` is

```
final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("image/money.gif");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " blah blah", "Text",
   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,   icon1);
```

If I wanted to show an image in `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, would it be the same for `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I don't think that the location is the problem because when I do this

```
menuPic = new javax.swing.JButton();
menuPic.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
    getClass().getResource("image/money.gif")));
```

It shows the image fine, but when I try to add an image to my `JOptionPane`, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same exact issue as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279532/code-to-display-an-image-wont-work-with-different-java-editors), but now in reverse. The key is *where* are the image files located. And the key to this is that you are now getting the image as a *File* while previously you were getting it as a *Resource*, and Java looks in two different places for these.

*Now* the files must be in an image subdirectory off of the user directory. You can get the user directory by calling

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Once you get the user directory, add an "/image/money.gif" to it, and that's the path to your image ***File*** (again, not a resource as you did in the previous example).

**Edit**
Regarding your comment:

> I don't think that the location is the problem because when i do this
>
> menuPic = new javax.swing.JButton();
>      menuPic.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image/money.gif")));
>
> It shows the image fine, but when i try to add an image to my joptionpane it doesn't show anything

Of course -- that's what I'm trying to say all long. In this second instance you're getting the image as a resource, not a file, and that makes a ***huge*** difference for where Java looks for the jpg file.

If for your JOptionPane you looked for the image as a resource, it will work fine since you know where the jpg resource is located.  i.e., this will likely work:

```
// final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("image/money.gif");
final ImageIcon icon1 = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image/money.gif"))
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " blah blah", "Text",
   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,   icon1);
```

But still if you want to find your image as a File -- and sometimes this is necessary, first you must find the user.dir as I've suggested above.

Comment: @JoshMo : Here is one more example explaining, [How to add  images to your Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659)